# What do we call people who stand in the street food shops selling their stuffs?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

[image: a person selling hot and cold beverages from a stand]

What do they call them in the UK?

Answer (score 5):

'Street seller' and 'Street vendor' are fairly neutral terms, but *two* words rather than a single word.

['Hawker'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawker_(trade)) and ['Peddler' / 'Pedlar' (Br.E.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peddler) are also used, but might have a more negative connotation (I'm not 100% sure, I'm not a native speaker). They're also used for people selling other kind of goods than food, and from e.g. a blanket rather than a cart.

> one who offers merchandise (such as fresh produce) for sale along the street or from door to door

<sub>(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peddler))</sub>

Answer (score 3):

In this specific case of a coffee stall we could say coffee vendor to describe the [**Barista**](https://nationalcareersservice.direct.gov.uk/job-profiles/barista).

The general phrase for seller of food and beverages and other mechandise is **Street Trader**
[Street Traders that serve hot food or drink at any time between the hours of
23.00 and 05.00 will also require a Premises Licence](https://www.oxford.gov.uk/download/downloads/id/385/street_trading_policy.pdf)

Peddlers are permitted either door to door or on the streets with a low cost certificate after they have lived in the area for 28 days, however their means of conveyance must be no more than a small trolley. If you work as a pedlar without a certificate - or let someone else use yours - you could be fined up to £200. (However you have to catch them first).

Fixed pitch licensing ranges from the cost of a peddlers certificate all the way up to £#,000's depending on locality, square area, spirits and duration. 
With a stall as shown we commonly use the single word **Stallholder** 
http://www.thamefoodfestival.co.uk/stallholder-selection-process/

> Definition of stallholder
>    chiefly British
>    : one who manages a stall at which articles are sold
>   https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stallholder

I disagree with the Cambridge definition of "a person who rents or owns a stall in a market"

Over the years markets halls have reduced and stalls are more commonly found in the street unless at a historic weekly market.

They are sometimes manned by an employee or franchise holder, but collectively holder is used when referring to a non specific group of people who **hold** [a fixed pitch with **a permanent licence**.](https://www.gov.uk/market-stall-licence)

"To fund his education he rented a stall at Portobello Market, bought bits and pieces from other stallholders, then sold them to the public at a healthy mark-up."

Some marketeers are now highly respectable think

Sir Richard Branson or Sir Alan Sugar

Interesting aside about this market stall the clock repair stall run by Mr Michael, whose well-known customers have included Richard Branson, Margaret Thatcher, Princess Diana and the Queen.  https://www.independent.co.uk/news/celebrated-fashion-market-is-forced-to-close-after-30-years-1119888.html

### Later Edit

The more traditional **single word** for a street seller is [costermonger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Costermonger) "... has come to be a synonym for street vendor"

Comment: I would say that the stallholder is the one whose name is on the lease.  The stall could be manned by an employee.  So not all people who stand and sell are stallholders.  “street vendors” is what I’d call them.